# Sending Test Email on Mailgun Returns 404 Not Found

Tags: curl, windows-10, mailgun

Can get some assistance on send my first email? Below is what I am trying to send. I am not sure if I am supposed to use created subdomain mg.example.com or example.com. The domain is 'active' and 'verified' in the mailgun dashboard.

Also there is a 'key' prefix before the api private key in the mailgun.org dashboard. Is this included in the cURL argument? I am on Windows 10.

This is the mailgun sample curl cmd from [their quickstart](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api):

`curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to=YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
    -F to=bar@example.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'`

This is my version of it:

`````
````
curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.example.com/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@example.com>' \
    -F to=me@gmail.com \
    -F to=bar@example.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
````
`````

I have also tried this version with both mg.example.com and example.com as the url. This is the response:

`````
````
curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/example.com/messages from='Excited User <mailgun@example.com>'
to=you@gmail.com to=bar@example.com subject='Hello' text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
````
`````

This is the error I am getting:

`````
    ````
    HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
server: nginx
date: Sun, 25 Sep 2016 11:40:43 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 182
connection: close
allow: POST, OPTIONS

&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"&gt;
&lt;title&gt;405 Method Not Allowed&lt;/title&gt;
&lt;h1&gt;Method Not Allowed&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;p&gt;The method GET is not allowed for the requested URL.&lt;/p&gt;
    ````
`````

First time ever doing this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, could you please help me on it. What have you used `-F from='Excited User <mailgun@example.com>'` , here i am using my own Email id.Please guide me on it ..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tested your url before 'curling' ?

```
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/https://mg.example.com/messages
```

is a concatenated string of two URLS.

Choose if it is

```
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/
```

or

```
https://mg.example.com/messages
```

Comment: Typo putting in SO, corrected. But the answer is no. I just tried just the url and mg.url. 'curl: (6) Could not resolve host:'. What does mailgun mean by active and verified. There is no hosted website but the dns is set...Thank for the guidance. Also, ````C:\Users\aarmand>curl https://api.mailgun.net/v3/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.</p><p>If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>````

Comment: I edit the url syntax after you had me looking at it. Error now is "method is not allowed".

Comment: `-X POST` if this need `POST`, here is a `GET` version (default)

Comment: Amazing. So the mailgun example is wrong for sending a message AND conflicts with there own [docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#sending)? I added -X Post and now the error is "from paramater missing" though it looks properly formated. Getting there. ```HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
server: nginx
date: Sun, 25 Sep 2016 13:05:32 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 46
connection: close

{
    "message": "'from' parameter is missing"
}```

Comment: Je me demande si je doit creer le conte email qui envoie l'email avant de l'utilizer...

Comment: ah ben oui, ya des chances. Sinon envoyer un mail avec la cmd du meme nom

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was putting the the entire curl statement on one line. I will have to learn how to use multiline curl in a windows environment.